# Python CSV Module read and write simultaneously

Tags: python, csv

I have two .csv files I am looking up data in one (file a) and matching it to the other (file b) once I find the appropriate row in b I want to write to a specific cell in the appropriate row.  Additionally I need to iterate over this so I will likely be writing to each row in file b potentially several times.

can I write to a csv file and then read it over and over again?

```
def match(name, group, cnum):
  for data in masterfile_list:
    if (name in data[0]):
        if (group in data[4]):
            if (cnum == "112"):
                data[7] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "111"):
                data[8] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "110"):
                data[9] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "109"):
                data[10] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "108"):
                data[11] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "107"):
                data[12] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "106"):
                data[13] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "105"):
                data[14] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "104"):
                data[15] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "103"):
                data[16] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "102"):
                data[17] = cnum
            elif (cnum == "101"):
                data[18] = cnum
```

I would ideally write/replace the line that matches.

Answer (score 2):

If file b is not extremely large I would suggest using `readlines()` to get a list of all lines and then iterate over the list and change lines as needed.  This will be quite a bit easier than seeking to different positions in the file and replacing lines.

Also, you can significantly reduce the code in the body of your function, I would probably do something like this:

```
def match(name, group, cnum):
    lookup = dict(zip(map(str, range(112, 100, -1)), range(7, 19)))
    for data in masterfile_list:
        if name in data[0] and group in data[4] and cnum in lookup:
            data[lookup[cnum]] = cnum
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I am new to this.  Can I still use the CSV module stuff if I use readline

Comment: @jimstandard1029: Typically, no, you don't use the `csv` module together with `readlines()`.  But the advice to read all your data into memory first still holds.  Instead of reading all the lines at once (as `readlines()` does), you will iterate over all the lines (via the `csv` module).  In the case of your "file b", you should just go ahead and iterate over the whole thing, loading *all* of it into memory in one shot before doing any lookups.  Then don't write anything out until you are *completely* done with your calculations, and write it *all* out at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your code fragment how you are opening/reading/writing the files in question.

To do what you describe you want, and if the files are not too large, I would read the relevant source files into memory, alter the structures you need to in memory, then write out the result to a file.

pseudocode

```
file_a=open('file_a','r')
file_b_things=open('file_b','r').readlines()

new_things_file=open('new_things','w')
new_things=[]

for thing in file_a:
    if thing in file_b_things:
      new_thing=do_something_with(thing)
      new_things.append(new_thing)

for new_thing in new_things:
  new_things_file.write(new_thing)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not easy to replace lines in a file. Normally, you would have to rewrite the file (in a secure way), if you want to make changes.

Except if you exactly know that the line size will not change - then you could `ftell()` before reading a line and `seek()` afterwards. But even that is not quite safe, because the `readline()` stuff in python does some buffering, i.e. the file pointer is nearer to the end than it should be.